# Problem requesting additional fields in REST2 api

Tags: sql, api, rest

I am using the RT::Extension::REST2 api (https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Extension::REST2) for a project and i am having a problem requesting additional fields in some requests.

I need to make a TicketSQL query and for performance reasons i am trying to obtain all the information of a ticket with something like /REST/2.0/ticket/8?fields=Requestor and i get something like

```
"Requestor": [
         {
                  "_url" : "http://<>/REST/2.0/user/example@example.com",
                  "id" : "example@example.com",
                  "type" : "user"
         },
         {
                  "_url" : "http://<>/REST/2.0/user/example@example.com",
                  "id" : "example@example.com",
                  "type" : "user"
         }
]
```

Notice it is a List of dictionaries, so when i try to do /REST/2.0/ticket/8?fields[Requestor]=Name the field Name does not appear on the dictionaries inside the list.

So i am trying to get something like this:

```
"Requestor": [
         {
                  "_url" : "http://<>/REST/2.0/user/example@example.com",
                  "id" : "example@example.com",
                  "type" : "user",
                  "Name" : "user20",
         },
         {
                  "_url" : "http://<>/REST/2.0/user/example@example.com",
                  "id" : "example@example.com",
                  "type" : "user",
                  "Name" : "user20",
         }
]
```

Is there any way i can do this ?

Thank you for your help!